# Problem using gmail to send email from my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gmail, gmail-api

```
Rails 4.2.1
Devise 3.4.1
```

I have an application that was working fine, but has not been used for about a year. I am trying to use it, and the first thing I tried to do, was reset my password. The application crashed, as I have the following setting in my environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

The application uses Devise, and I am using a Gmail account

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_smtp_server,
  port: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_smtp_port,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

The application also uses Google's reCaptcha for the resetting the password form.

First thing I attempted, was setting "Less secure app access" to ON, for the Google Account, but that did not work, then following advice from Stackoverflow, I did:

```
accounts.google.com/b/1/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
```

to unlock Google's email CAPTCHA

This time, resetting the password from my browser worked fine. However, when someone, from another location, tried resetting their password, the app crashed, with the old message in the log file:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv):
```

When I tried his email address, in the reset password form, from my browser, it worked.

I guess this must be related to some security changes, Google did, over the past year. Is my only solution, not using CAPTCHA (which would be a problem), or is there another solution?

Comment: Recently I encountered the same problem. I've done the same process that you did. Then, I tried to put the original gmail username and password in the config file instead of using the secrets and env variable. Surprisingly, it works! Then, I had to revert back to secrets and reboot the hosting and restart app and web server couple of times, then it works. Wired!

Comment: Is anyone else, beside you, using your applications?